# how to restore dump of all memcache keys stored in a file using memcache-tool correctly?

Tags: linux, caching

**Step 1. taking dump of memcached keys from localhost**

```
shub@S04:/usr/share/memcached/scripts$ ./memcached-tool localhost:11211 dump > /tmp/backup.log
Dumping memcache contents
Number of buckets: 1
Number of items  : 4
Dumping bucket 1 - 4 total items
```

**Step 2. restoring dump to one of the internal server**

```
shub@S04:/usr/share/memcached$ nc 10.0.2.182 11112 < /tmp/test.log 
STORED
STORED
STORED
STORED
```

**Step 3. But when I ran stats, I only found 1 item whereas there were 4 items restored in the above command.**

```
shub@S04:/usr/share/memcached/scripts$ echo "stats items" | nc 10.0.2.182 11112
STAT items:1:number 1
STAT items:1:age 588
STAT items:1:evicted 0
STAT items:1:evicted_nonzero 0
STAT items:1:evicted_time 0
STAT items:1:outofmemory 0
STAT items:1:tailrepairs 0
STAT items:1:reclaimed 24
STAT items:1:expired_unfetched 24
STAT items:1:evicted_unfetched 0
END
```

So I want a command that will restore the complete dump, here I think it is overwriting  data on the same slab.

Comment: Did you look at the contents of the dump?

Comment: Yes,  as you can see in step 3, it just returned a single item. I have seen it using "stats cacahedump " command.

Answer (score 0):

The log you export as this:

```
add key 32 timestamp 135 /r/n
value /r/n
```

when you resore this data to new memcache, the timestamp has been overdue, so you must modify timestamp as 0 or some future timestamp,（0 is never to due）.